# can have definition variable of non-literal type in constexpr function body c++14?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr, c++14

I think that in C++14 more restrictives are removed from constexpr. But according N3797 7.1.5 3-punct:

---

The definition of a contexpr function shall satisfy the following constraints:

- it shall not be virtual
- its return type shall be a literal type;
- each of its parameters types shall be a literal type;
- its *function-body* shall be = **delete**, = **default**, or a *compound-statement* that does not contain:
- an *asm-definition*,
- a **goto** statement,
- a *try-block*, or
- a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread storage duration or for which no initialization is
  performed.

---

I know why static, thread storage duration variables are disallowed, but I don't see any reason, why ONLY allowed definition of a variable of  literal type ?

Or I'm not understand the standard.

I'm not sure, but according standard following errors should be created even C++14:

```
struct point{
constexpr point(): x(0), y(0){}
constexpr point(int x_, int y_): x(x_),y(y_){}
constexpr int hypot()const { return x*x + y*y; }
int x,y;
};

constexpr int hypot(int x, int y) {  
   point p{x,y}; //error, because p - is not literal type.
   return p.hypot();
}

// error, because return type is not literal.
constexpr point  getPoint(int x, int y) { return {x,y}; }

// error, because parameter is not literal.
constexpr int hypot(point p) { return p.hypot(); }
```

**Q: If really above errors would happen, why these restrictions are not removed?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*literal type* is defined in 3.9/10:

> A type is a *literal type* if it is:
>
> - `void`; or
> - a scalar type; or
> - a reference type; or
> - an array of literal type; or
> - a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties:
>
>   - it has a trivial destructor,
>   - it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one `constexpr` constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move constructor, and
>   - all of its non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types

So your struct `point` *is* a literal type and your sample code is valid C++1y.

As to why `constexpr` functions are restricted to variables of literal type, they are the only types that are guaranteed to be interpretable at compile time.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that literal types are only integer, char, string-literal and float literals. I fix getPoint.